# Direction in curl of potential vector when z is not the axial direction

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
I’m reading the third part of the problem. And here is the solution. What confuses me is that if we replace the x axis with z axis, then there is nothing changed, right? At the end when calculating the curl of A, it still points to the theta direction, but now the direction points out the page instead. And why does the theta direction is into the page when the x axis is the axial direction?

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates, the $\theta$ direction wraps around the axis of rotational symmetry according to the right-hand rule. (Specifically if your right thumb points along the axis of symmetry, then $\hat{\theta}$ wraps around that axis in the direction that your fingers curl.)  This means that in the diagram, $\hat{\theta}$ points out of the page above the line that the charge is traveling along, and points into the page below that line.  Since we are looking at the field at a point below the line of travel, we have $\hat{\theta}$ pointing into the page.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for comment.